# Is there any way to automate key rotation in Azure PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql, azure, encryption

I want to automate the process of rotating encryption key for Azure Postgre Sql. There are no commands available in PowerShell or CLI for key rotation or updating the key.
Is there any other way for key rotation with minimal manual intervention?

Answer (score 0):

The encryption key should be stored in Azure Key Vault, then you can rotate the keys using powershell and also create Azure Functions with powershell(one way to automate you could use time trigger to schedule the execution).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-data-encryption-portal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/quick-create-powershell

Comment: Hi Thiago, I want to use BYOK approach for PostgreSql encryption. Once I update the customer key(KEK) in key vault, what would be next steps for PostgreSql. Please share .net core libraries which can be used here for making changes to PostgreSql.